# Strange CSS "appear" in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a problem with the jQuery plugin in this demo page: http://fgte.st/SocialCount/examples/index.html

If you open it in Firefox you'll see the social sharing buttons and everything works just fine. But in Chrome there's a strange CSS computed that makes the buttons hidden:

```
.social_widget, .social_widget_container, .social_widget_item, .social_wrapper, .social_wrapper2, .social_youtube, .socialbadge, .socialbarwrapper, .socialbkmark, .socialbox, .socialbox2, .socialboxp, .socialbtns, .socialbuttons, .socialchrome-grid, .socialcount, .socialdigg, .socialh, .socialicons, .socialimglink {
    display: none;
}
```

The strange part is that this code isn't present in the sorce code of the page, neither in the CSS files.

How is that even possible?

Comment: Probably you have an extension installed in Chrome that blocks social media buttons/content, something like `AdBlock` or another privacy AddOn.

Comment: Check your Chrome extensions to see what is installed - these can add CSS to the page. A simple check might be to open the site in Incognito mode which disables most extensions.

Comment: The problem was AdBlock Plus, thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be this issue due to some plugins **(extensions)** installed on your Chrome Browser. Please see is there any such plugin installed on your Chrome browser?

If yes, then try again after uninstalling them from the Chrome browser.

Comment: Hey!!! What's the problem? Why did this answer get down-voted?? May I know the reason please?

Comment: I haven't thought about this, thank you! The problem was AdBlock Plus.